# Is secure to Fetch Data from BlockFrost from the Front-End?

Tags: blockfrost

I am building a daap, but I must fetch data from Blockfrost in order to make the transaction, I am not sure if should i Add my personal project ID in a request from the front end. Currently i have that in my backend as an .env variable and my back end does the request and sends back the info to the front End. I was thinking about to change it to the Front End so that my server does not have to listen all that requests. But i am afraid it may compromise the security of my project Id

Answer (score 2):

It is not a recommended practice, as you said yourself, it will leak your security token to the public.

Blockfrost is an alternative way to access the Cardano blockchain, it is not a replacement for your own backends.